# How do I "isolate" properties passed to EmberJS components from the original objects

Tags: ember.js

I have a "multi-selector" component that receives an array of objects as a parameter.

I need to find a way to clone the parameter inside the component so that when I change stuff to it, the original array that was passed doesn't change, muddying the scope.

Here's my example. The issue that I'd like to change elements in the `items` array in the component without touching the `states` array in the model.

The component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  update: function() {
    var ids = [];

    this.get('items').map(function(item) {
      if(item.checked) {
        ids.push(item.id);
      }
    });

    this.sendAction('updateAction', ids);
  }.observes('items.@each.checked')
});
```

And the template:

```
<div class="multi-selector">
  {{#each item in items}}
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.checked}}
        {{item.title}}
      </label>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

The way I call it:

```
{{multi-selector
  items=model.states
  updateAction='selectStatesFromMultiSelector'
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we can't use [oneWayBindings](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/) , because the elements in the array will still be just references.

> A one-way binding only propagates changes in one direction.

In this case, generating your own internal list should work better:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  listItems: null,
  makeItem: function(item) { 
    return Ember.Object.create(item.getProperties('id', 'checked', 'title'));
  }),
  cloneItems: function() { 
    this.set('listItems', this.get('items').map(this.makeItem));
  }.observes('items'),

  update: function() {
    var ids = [];
    this.get('listItems').map(function(item) {
      if(item.checked) {
        ids.push(item.id);
      }
    });
    this.sendAction('updateAction', ids);
  }.observes('listItems.@each.checked')
});
```

And use listItems in the template

```
<div class="multi-selector">
  {{#each item in listItems}}
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.checked}}
        {{item.title}}
      </label>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: How would you implement this in the context of a component?

Comment: I tried this and, for some reason it doesn't work. The objects are still bound both ways..

Comment: Right, because the objects in the array will still be just references, see my update

Answer (score 1):

Just create a shadow array that holds the cloned `items` array and use that.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
 copyOfItems: null,

 cloneItems: function() { 
  this.set('copyOfItems', this.get('items').map(function(item) { return item; }));
 }.on('didInsertElement'),

  update: function() {
   var ids = [];
   this.get('copyOfItems').map(function(item) {
     if(item.checked) {
      ids.push(item.id);
    }
  });
   this.sendAction('updateAction', ids);
  }.observes('copyOfItems.@each.checked')
});
```

use the same shadow variable in your component's template.

Comment: Are you sure that `copyOfItems` won't be shared/clobbered if you have multiple of these components on a page?

Comment: Weirdly enough this still preserves the bindings.

Comment: @torazaburo now that I'm thinking about it, it might do that, so a better way would be to set it in the `init` or `on('init)`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @torazaburo or I could just make the initial value of that `null`